# clustring using mahalanobis distance in r

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I have data set of 5,000 people with 60 parameters.
I want to cluster them using mahalanobis distance, I saw few Questions in here in the subject and I am little confused.
can I use the mahalanobis function from "stats" and then use kmeans function from "stats"?
if I don't have centers in advanced (that's the point i want the cluster to find the centers and cluster every person) what can i do?
how do I compute the cov right? it doesn't work without it.

I would appreciate it if someone can explain it to me because I want to do it right.

step 1:

```
mah_dist <- mahalanobis(x, center, cov, inverted = FALSE, ...)
```

step 2:

## Determine number of clusters

```
wss <- (nrow(mah_dist)-1)*sum(apply(mah_dist,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mah_dist, 
                                     centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

kmeans(mah_dist, k=10)
```

Comment: It is not a recommended method for clustering in general.

Comment: I agree with bethanyP's point.

Comment: @bethanyP why isn't is a recommend method? I have a  correlated medical data to work on and I've heard that could be good to try. anyhow, after clustering I am planning on using a classifier, so if its not good wouldn't I be able to know when I see the result?

Comment: I do know there are clustering methods which use Mahanolobis between cluster centroids as a decision threshold. If you use a Bradley, Fayyad, Reina clustering algorithm, that is one possible method.